# Style.css (i.e) External css file does not work in bootstrap 3.3.2 latest version

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on Bootstrap 3.3.2 Version. But In that I wrote Some external CSS and it stored in style.css file. But that external file does not work. 
I have mentioned link in following format:

```
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

But it could not be taken. Please Help Me

Comment: Try adding `rel="stylesheet"` to it and also make sure the file is in correct folder path

Comment: try adding 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />... make sure your folder path is correct.